# Determining geolocation of customer number in Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am creating a solution with Service Cloud Voice (Salesforce + Amazon Connect).

Is there a way to determine geolocation of a customer's phone number using Amazon Location Service (or any other solution) within Amazon Connect?

I have a use case where call recording should be disabled by default if a customer is in a specific US State.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to reliably determine geolocation from just calling party information.

Amazon Connect provides you with the "Customer Number" attribute when the voice contact arrives in your contact flow, which is effectively the caller id.  You can't verify that the number you've been presented with in this attribute is actually the caller's real number, as many telcos allow you to change or override this at the time of call setup.  The number presented could also reside in a different state than the entry point to the Public Switched Telephone network (PSTN), so if you're requirement is a legal or regulatory requirement then you should clearly understand the definition of the customer being "in" a specific US State.  Numbers are also portable, so the number may reside in a state other than the one the Area Code (NPA) and Exchange (NXX) map to in the North American Numbering Plan's database.

Additionally, [Wireless Local Number Portability](https://www.fcc.gov/general/wireless-local-number-portability-wlnp) allows mobile phones to have numbers that were originally assigned to wirelines via porting.  Since mobile phones are able to move across state lines with restriction, this may problematic depending on your definition of "in" a specific US State.

If you're organization felt it was acceptable to use the NPA and NXX information to determine if the call should be recorded or not, then you could download a geographic area code report from the North American Number Plan Administrator [here](https://nationalnanpa.com/reports/reports_npa.html) and use this information in a lambda-based lookup in your contact flow.